# How to minify a css file with grunt and compile it into JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, gruntjs

I'm a grunt biginner and yet I just know how to use grunt concat and uglify. Now I need some help with css minification, grunt copy and liveload and other tasks.

Now I need to build a UI system for my JS widget, so I'm thinking of add variables into css files(like less in someway) and compile(replace variable with real style) it into real css. But I can't use less for my widget is 20k in whole, LESS is too big for it.

I seem need to use grunt to do stuff like mincss and i-dont-know-what to compile it into a js file in shape of a variable. And I need to LiveLoad it and more other tast to make the whole progress automatic.

Here is what I want to do:

style.css:

```
.a{
  width: $aWidth;
  color: $aColor;
}
```

This is something I want to write in the css file which is not a real css actually.

first minify it(i don't know if the fake css could be minified?): style.min.css

```
.a{width: $aWidth;color: $aColor;}
```

then compile it into a css.js(just add a "var css = ", this is where halt me mostly):

```
var css = ".a{width: $aWidth;color: $aColor;}";
```

I'll do simple RegExp replacement in my js to make it a real css, a easy and simple less.js.
concat it which I know how to do...

Copy the concated file widget.js into my nginx static file folder for local test.(This use grunt copy?)

Auto run all these tasks above and refresh the page when I save/change style.css file(this use the watch? or liveload? and perhaps I need two sets of settings to watch the css or the js).

That's all I need, and I believe it's gonna help for more grunt beginners.
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to convert a CascadingStyleSheet into JavaScript, but that is really strange. I think you mean something else.

Comment: Is there any other ways to use css with variables without using LESS?

Comment: There is SASS, it's essentially the same as LESS. Why can't you use LESS exactly? You can always just serve a compiled CSS on your live site.

Comment: I mean something not that big... i mentioned that the whole widget is just 20k, so I have to make it simple by doing this on my own. I believe the LESS is basically doing similar things. Also, the value of the variables is loaded somewhere else, i don't have a complete compiled version until the widget is loaded with a config file. So I can't compile the css in advance.

Comment: That sounds really strange to me. Is your CSS determined dynamically? (like, by some JavaScript?).

Comment: Yes it is. And I should not put the config file into the js, it's dynamically compiled within the browser.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. css is used for styling with classes and js for manipulating the DOM element classes. Why do you need to have css inside js ?

Comment: First it's a small js plugin which can be installed into any sites so I have to minimize the network connections, and i need js to write html/dom and css. Second, it's a ui system, so I need different skins, which means different css with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can actually use `less` in combination with [grunt-ucss](https://github.com/ullmark/grunt-ucss). From the README:

> The task can do two things; Analyze html+css using ucss and print out any unused selectors in the grunt log and use that information to create new clean